# how to resolve CORS issue

Tags: angular, cors

I built a manga website, just to practice, I finished the project in angular, when I uploaded it in GitHub, it can't access the API and throws the cors error.
Is there a way to fix this ?
I used the Mangadex API, why would they give their API to public if you can't use it?

I couldn't find any solution, some said to use proxy (I don't know how), I used some Chrome extension  for cors but it gave all images as their promotional images (read this manga at Mangadex website).

Comment: the service will have to support cors

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Instead, include it as formatted text in the body of your question.

Comment: Presumably there is a way to configure the public API to allow for CORS requests from your domain, unless the assumption is that you are only calling it from the backend and never a browser.  You will most likely need to read through the APIs documentation to get a better idea of how it is intended to be used.

Comment: If you serve your Angular app via Node, ASP.NET, etc, you'll have a server-side layer you can make requests to that API with. Your Angular app would call itself on a route that's handled by the server-side code, thus bypassing the CORS requirement as you're making a server-to-server call versus an XMLHttpRequest

Comment: i was not making call with server side, as you guys here said i am making the call with XMLHttpRequest, maybe that is the problem, i will try to make the server side layer now, what i got is, i should make the call with node then pass the data to the angular to render.

Answer (score 0):

**step 1:** create a file named **proxy.conf.json** in the root directory, which will be used to setup proxy in angular, and the content in the proxy file eg

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:5200",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

here **'/api'** refers that this config is used for all the end-point which includes **'/api'** (can setup multiple like **'/user'**, **'/db'** etc) and the target is the address where the backend is running as in above its just an local host, can be any other IP address(like AWS ec2 instance IP)

**Step 2:** update angular.json file
add in the angular configuration inside **architect => serve**

```
"options": {
            "browserTarget": "sample-project:build",
            "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
          }
```

For more info can refer to the official docs : https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server

**Just FYI:** One of the most popular npm package to configure CORS: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors it can help you to understand how to configure it on backend servers

**P.S:** To Resolve CORS there are multiple ways to fix it like configuration of CORS policies to be used on backend, updating https headers etc